# When sorting array the list duplicates

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, foreach, innerhtml

I have a fetch from an API (sorted alphabetically) which I have put in an array ("peopleArray"). This array I iterate over in a forEach.

I want to be able to reverse the order of the list. However, every time a click my "sorting"-button the list duplicates itself in the reverse order.

How do I get it to rewrite/replace/rearrange the original list instead of adding a new reversed one? What am I missing in my sorting?

This is my original forEach

```
peopleArray.forEach((person) => {
      cardbox.innerHTML += `
          <div class="cardliststyle">
          <img class="profilepic" src="${person.picture.medium}" alt="picture" />
          <span class="circle"></span>
          <span class="square"></span>
            <div class="bg-white">
            <div class="name-city">
              <p class="name">${person.name.first} ${person.name.last}</p>
              <p class="city">${person.location.city}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="phone-email">
              <a class="email" href="mailto:${person.email}"> <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></a>
              <a class="phone" href="tel:${person.phone}"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i></a>
            </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

And this is the sorting-function/ forEach

```
sort.addEventListener("click", function () {
  peopleArray.reverse();

  peopleArray.forEach((person) => {
    cardbox.innerHTML += `
    <div class="cardliststyle">
    
      <img class="profilepic" src="${person.picture.medium}" alt="picture" />
      <div class="bg-white">
      <div class="name-city">
        <p class="name">${person.name.first} ${person.name.last}</p>
        <p class="city">${person.location.city}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="phone-email">
        <a class="email" href="mailto:${person.email}"> <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></a>
        <a class="phone" href="tel:${person.phone}"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i></a>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
`;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clear the list before appending new elements.

```js
sort.addEventListener("click", function () {
  peopleArray.reverse();
  cardbox.innerHTML = '';
  peopleArray.forEach((person) => {
    cardbox.innerHTML += `...`
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is what I was missing, knew it was something like that but couldn't figure it out. I am too used to working with React and states...

Answer (score 0):

As the content is already rendered on your page your reverse function can be greatly simplified, see below:

```js
const cont=document.getElementById("someContainer");

document.querySelector("button").onclick=ev=>[...cont.children].reverse().forEach(div=>cont.append(div));
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css"/>
<button>reverse list</button>
<div id="someContainer">
<div class="cardliststyle">
      <img class="profilepic" src="https://picsum.photos/id/201/200/120" alt="picture" />
      <span class="circle"></span>
      <span class="square"></span>
        <div class="bg-white">
        <div class="name-city">
          <p class="name">Harry Potter</p>
          <p class="city">Wisteria Lane</p>
        </div>
        <div class="phone-email">
          <a class="email" href="mailto:hp@hogwarts.edu"> <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></a>
          <a class="phone" href="tel:+44 007"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i></a>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>

<div class="cardliststyle">
      <img class="profilepic" src="https://picsum.photos/id/202/200/120" alt="picture" />
      <span class="circle"></span>
      <span class="square"></span>
        <div class="bg-white">
        <div class="name-city">
          <p class="name">Ron Weasley</p>
          <p class="city">Diagon Alley</p>
        </div>
        <div class="phone-email">
          <a class="email" href="mailto:rw@hogwarts.edu"> <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></a>
          <a class="phone" href="tel:+44 0815"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i></a>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>

<div class="cardliststyle">
      <img class="profilepic" src="https://picsum.photos/id/203/200/120" alt="picture" />
      <span class="circle"></span>
      <span class="square"></span>
        <div class="bg-white">
        <div class="name-city">
          <p class="name">Hermione Granger</p>
          <p class="city">Muggle Land</p>
        </div>
        <div class="phone-email">
          <a class="email" href="mailto:hg@hogwarts.edu"> <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></a>
          <a class="phone" href="tel:+44 4711"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i></a>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Really simplified and fabulous (but definitely not a junior) solution.